# Looking for structured US Secretary of State public schedule

Tags: data-request, usa, state, federal

I'm trying to track down a structured version of the public schedule for the Secretary of State, during Clinton's term. I don't care about under/deputy/assistant secretaries either, just the Secretary.

The data is available online here: http://www.state.gov/r/pa/prs/appt/index.htm. It has many (but not all) days. However, it's messy and unstructured enough that simple web parsing is unreliable.  So, does anyone know if this is already available in a structured format?

To clarify, I'm interested in specific events with time and a description. Perhaps an XML calendar feed (but I want data back to 2009). Another idea would be a CSV with columns for Date, Time, Description, and Media Coverage:

```
2015-11-14,9:40 a.m. LOCAL,"Secretary Kerry meets with the Tunisian National Dialogue Quartet, in Tunis, Tunisia.",(CLOSED PRESS COVERAGE)
2015-11-14,10:30 a.m. LOCAL,"Secretary Kerry participates in the U.S.-Tunisia Strategic Dialogue Plenary, in Tunis, Tunisia.",(POOLED CAMERA SPRAY AT THE TOP)
```

Comment: rss feed is well structured....did you try that?